# Why JPA commit fails in Application, but works in JUnit?

Tags: spring, jpa, junit

I am trying to reproduce a JPA exception that I have in my Spring Boot application in a JUnit.

Application (commit fails):

```
@Import(RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration.class)
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner {

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Inject
    Repository1 repository1;
    ...    

    @Inject
    RepositoryN repositoryN;

    @Override
    public void run(final String... args) throws Exception {
        // Populating database with demo data
        repository1.save(entity1);
        ...

        // fails on save entityN
        repositoryN.save(entityN);
    }
}
```

JUnit (works - why?):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { PersistenceConfig.class, DataConfig.class },
        loader = AnnotationConfigContextLoader.class)
@Transactional("transactionManager.data")
@ActiveProfiles("dev")
public class BuildingFloorsRoomsRepositoryTest {
    @Inject
    Repository1 repository1;
    ...    

    @Inject
    RepositoryN repositoryN;

    @Test
    @Rollback(false)
    public void saveEntities() {
        repository1.save(entity1);
        ...
        repositoryN.save(entityN);
        // works - why?
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.archibus.domain.hierarchy.Node
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:801)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:794)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:97)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:350)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:293)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:161)
    at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:118)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeBeforeSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:432)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:265)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:84)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:811)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:784)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:789)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:389)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference I can see is that the test is running in a transaction. Try to execute the `run` within a transaction with `@Transactional` or similar.